# Hearthstone-style graphics with After Effects

Tags: after-effects, animation, effects

I'd like to make some graphics like Hearthstone with After Effects. But I'm having trouble finding the right technique to simulate that look. After some research, I found the way that the Blizzard developers make their graphics, but they use coding. How can I achieve similar results with After Effects?

Here's an [example](http://hearthforge.co.nf/medivh/). And there is [another](http://hearthforge.co.nf/magni/).

I already figured out how to mask-map(?) using colors thanks to [Stib](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/1950/stib) in this [post](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18322/is-possible-to-use-this-map-as-a-mask-after-effects).
But now I'm trying to figure out how to make this "warpy" thing, based on the color map:

[image: Warpy Thing]

I do have the way they make the particles effects and all that stuff in mind, but their technique is way more practical. In deep research some techniques came to me, like Plasma, but they're all coding techniques.
PS: I do know about the displacement mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few effects to take a look at, which may get you closer to the result you are looking for. These effects are based on your helpful thumbnails:

Effect > Stylize > Glow / Trapcode Shine (uSampler1)

Effect > Noise & Grain > Fractal Noise + Turbulent Displace (uSampler2)

Effect > Generate > 4-Color Gradient (uSampler3)

Effect > Noise & Grain > Fractal Noise w/ Default Settings (uSampler4)

Effect > Color Correction > Colorama (uSampler5)

These styles require heavy experimentation, so play around with Track Mattes, Blending Modes, and importing textures and other source imagery to help achieve these results. Good luck!